# Spacing issue when NiceMatrixBlock is inside an equation

Tags: nicematrix

I need to use `NiceMatrixBlock` *inside* an equation, but doing so provokes spacing issues. Is there a way to fix that?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools,nicematrix}

\begin{document}

A test equation:
\begin{align}
   e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{align}

With NiceMatrixBlock outside align:
\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]%
   \begin{align}
      \begin{dcases}
         \begin{NiceArrayWithDelims}{[}{]}{cc}
            a     &b\\
            ccccc &d\\
         \end{NiceArrayWithDelims}
         \\
         \begin{NiceArrayWithDelims}{[}{]}{ccc}
            a  &b &c\\
            d  &e &f\\
         \end{NiceArrayWithDelims}
      \end{dcases}
   \end{align}
\end{NiceMatrixBlock}

With NiceMatrixBlock inside align:
\begin{align}
   \begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]%
   \begin{dcases}
      \begin{NiceArrayWithDelims}{[}{]}{cc}
         a     &b\\
         ccccc &d\\
      \end{NiceArrayWithDelims}
      \\
      \begin{NiceArrayWithDelims}{[}{]}{ccc}
         a  &b &c\\
         d  &e &f\\
      \end{NiceArrayWithDelims}
   \end{dcases}
   \end{NiceMatrixBlock}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `nicematrix`. I have posted on CTAN a new version of `nicematrix` (v. 2.23, 2023-09-02) which solves that problem.

Answer (score 2):

It gets confused by the measuring pass, the nicematrix maintainer usually passes by and will probably provide a better answer, but a simple workaround is to do the nicematrix block first in a box.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools,nicematrix}
\newbox\hmmm
\begin{document}

A test equation:
\begin{align}
   e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{align}



With NiceMatrixBlock outside align:
\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]%
   \begin{align}
      \begin{dcases}
         \begin{NiceArrayWithDelims}{[}{]}{cc}
            a     &b\\
            ccccc &d\\
         \end{NiceArrayWithDelims}
         \\
         \begin{NiceArrayWithDelims}{[}{]}{ccc}
            a  &b &c\\
            d  &e &f\\
         \end{NiceArrayWithDelims}
      \end{dcases}
   \end{align}
\end{NiceMatrixBlock}


With NiceMatrixBlock inside align:
\setbox\hmmm=\hbox{$%
   \begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]%
   \begin{dcases}
      \begin{NiceArrayWithDelims}{[}{]}{cc}
         a     &b\\
         ccccc &d\\
      \end{NiceArrayWithDelims}
      \\
      \begin{NiceArrayWithDelims}{[}{]}{ccc}
         a  &b &c\\
         d  &e &f\\
      \end{NiceArrayWithDelims}
   \end{dcases}
   \end{NiceMatrixBlock}$}
\begin{align}
aaa&bbb\\
\usebox\hmmm
&ccc
\end{align}


\begin{align}
   e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

[image]